# Laravel 5 mock a Eloquent model

Tags: php, phpunit, laravel-5

I'm testing one of my controllers and no matter what I try I get the error that the `all()` function doesn't exist.

```
Static method Mockery_1_App_Models_User::all() does not exist on this mock object
```

My test method:

```
/**
 * Test index page
 * @return void
 */
public function testIndexAsUser()
{
    $this->beUser();

    // The method calls the mock objects should receive
    $this->user->shouldReceive('all')->once()->andReturn([]);

    // Call index page
    $response = $this->call('GET', 'users');

    // Assertions
    $this->assertResponseOk();
    $this->assertViewHas('user');
    $this->assertViewNameIs('users.show');
}
```

My mocking method:

```
/**
 * Mock a class
 * @param  string $class
 * @return Mockery
 */
public function mock($class)
{
    $mock = Mockery::mock('Eloquent', $class);

    app()->instance($class, $mock);

    return $mock;
}
```

My actual controller method:

```
/**
 * Show all users
 * @return Response
 */
public function getIndex()
{
    $users = $this->user->all();

    return view('users.index');
}
```

Am I using the wrong Eloquent class in my mock object or something? Since Laravel 5 the models are not referring to Eloquent but to `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` but I've tried that too.

Comment: There is a good chance this is related to the fact that Laravel 5 is not yet in Beta - and the "testing" functions of Laravel 5 are not yet finished. I wouldnt spend too much time on it until Taylor finishes of all the testing support for L5

Comment: Did you try `Mockery::mock('Model', $class)` or `Mockery::mock('App\Model', $class)`? (I know you said you tried with the full namespace - but did you try the short versions?)

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to mock an Eloquent model is by using partials:

```
$mock = m::mock('MyModelClass')->makePartial();
```

However, it won't help you much as you're using a static method (`all()`). PHP's not-so-strict nature lets you call static methods in a non-static way (`$user->all()`), but you should avoid it. Instead you should do it the heavy-handed way:

```
$users = $this->user->newQuery()->get();
```

This can be mocked:

```
$mockUser->shouldReceive('newQuery->get')->andReturn([/*...*/]);
```

If you want to take this one step further, move the `get()` call into a separate repository class that is injected into the controller, which will make it easier to mock. You can find plenty of articles on the repository pattern online.